# No Data in array github Api Swift

Tags: json, swift, github, tableview

How do I get the "names" from the if let statement into my tableview? The code triggers the else block right now. I am trying to parse the name data from the github api. Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var tableArray = [String] ()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    parseJSON()

}

func parseJSON () {

    let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error ) in

    guard error == nil else {
        print("returned error")
        return
    }

    guard let content = data else {
        print("No data")
        return
    }

    guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, 
options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? 
[String: Any] else {
        print("Not containing JSON")
        return
    }

    if let array = json["name"] as? [String] {
        self.tableArray = array
    } else {

        print("Name is blank")

        }

    print(self.tableArray)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    }

    task.resume()
}

}

extension ViewController {

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.tableArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.tableArray.count



}

}
```

Right now it's displaying "name is blank" in the console. I am trying to get the names of the users and display them in a tableview. Other url's seem to work, but I can't seem to figure out Github. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure `name` is an array of strings and not just a `string`? Before your `if let` statement, add `print(json)` and see what is the value of the key `name`

Comment: Yes, tried this and it still output is  "name is blank" . What I'm really trying to do is get a list of the user's public repos. Very confused.

Comment: What was the output from `print(json)`?

Comment: I get a bunch of apis '"repository_search_url": https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}, "following_url": https://api.github.com/user/following{/target}, "code_search_url": https://api.github.com/search/code?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}, "events_url": https://api.github.com/events, "user_repositories_url": https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}]
Json is not displaying
[]'

Answer (score 1):

Your mistakes is.
 1. Used wrong url.
 2. Wrong mapping response

https://api.github.com Return Api list.
https://api.github.com/users/ Return user list.

Function fetchNameOfUsers
1. Implement request by use "user list" url.
2. Mapping the response by use "user list" structure.

```
func fetchNameOfUsers() {
  guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users") else {
    return
  }
  let request = URLRequest(url: url)
  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else {
      return // Error
    }
    guard let data = data, let _ = response else {
      return // No data
    }
    guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] else {
      return // Not [String: Any] list
    }
    let nameOfUsers = json.compactMap {
      $0["login"] as? String
    }
    let displayedNameOfUsers = nameOfUsers.joined(separator: ", ")
    print(displayedNameOfUsers)
  }.resume()
}
```

To see result call function fetchNameOfUsers.

```
fetchNameOfUsers()
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this url and it still outputs "name is blank". Very frustrating. I can't seem to figure this out.